# How to handle exceptions in the middle of PostgreSQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, hstore

I have a table with some columns in hstore, such as vleads.extended_columns -> 'date_of_birth'. The value for this particular field is generally a string of the form '13/08/2014' but can be cast to a date. However, some rows may contain a badly-formed string.

My challenge is to be able to perform an AGE operation on this field in a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "vleads"  
WHERE "vleads"."campaign_id" IS NULL 
AND ( 
((vleads.lead_type_id = 5) OR (vleads.lead_type_id = 7) OR (vleads.lead_type_id = 1)) 
AND ((vleads.extended_columns -> 'interested_in_personal_accident' = 'Sim')) 
AND (((EXTRACT (YEAR FROM AGE((to_date(vleads.extended_columns -> 'date_of_birth', 'DD/MM/YYYY')))))::int) <= 60)) 
AND ((date_trunc('day', ((fill_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo')) = ('2014-03-13 00:00:00 -0300' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo'))
    )
```

This works until a malformed string appears in the data; then the cast fails.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "vleads"  
WHERE "vleads"."campaign_id" IS NULL 
AND ( 
((vleads.lead_type_id = 5) OR (vleads.lead_type_id = 7) OR (vleads.lead_type_id = 1)) 
AND ((vleads.extended_columns -> 'interested_in_personal_accident' = 'Sim')) 
AND (((EXTRACT (YEAR FROM AGE((BEGIN to_date(vleads.extended_columns -> 'date_of_birth', 'DD/MM/YYYY') EXCEPTION to_date('01/01/1900', 'DD/MM/YYYYY') END))))::int) <= 60)) 
AND ((date_trunc('day', ((fill_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo')) = ('2014-03-13 00:00:00 -0300' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo'))
    )
```

and get

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_date"
LINE 1: ...t' = 'Sim')) AND (((EXTRACT (YEAR FROM AGE((BEGIN to_date(vl...
                                                         ^
```

Is there any way to get this query to execute even if there's malformed data in a row? Obviously for bad rows I'm trying to exclude the result (which is why I substitute '01/01/1900'). I'm unclear whether the problem is the BEGIN---END syntax or the fact I'm doing it on an store value.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: You will need to write your own (PL/pgSQL) function that accepts a String tries to convert it and returns NULL if an exception occurs

Comment: Imho, you should not rely on a hstore field to get your query working. In doing this you bypass the type mechanism and that leads to this kind of errors. If you have queries that rely on a field to be there, set it as a table's column even if it is nullable.